# Using image generator with GridSearchCV fit

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn, grid-search

I scaled images with `ImageDataGenerator` a feature of `keras`. So, I have `train_generator`, `valid_generator` and `test_generator`. But `fit` function of `GridSearchCV` accepts two variable. example: `grid.fit(X,y)`. But I dont have these data. How can i use fit generator with grid search?
My codes:

```
def create_model(learn_rate = 0.001,momentum = 0):
    model.add(
    .
    .
    .

    return model


model = KerasClassifier(build_fn = create_model, verbose = 0)

grid = GridSearchCV(estimator = model, param_grid = param_grid, n_jobs = -1, cv = 10)


grid_result = grid.fit(??)
```